# Masonite Route Parameters with slash does not work

Tags: masonite

My Routes:

```
Get().route('/amp/@website', 'PageController@amp_info').name('amp_info'),
Get().route('/@website', 'PageController@info').name('info')
```

This works: https://websiteopedia.com/www.eventsnow.com 
this does not https://websiteopedia.com/https://www.eventsnow.com/

What do I need to do differently?  the slash in params redirected to the 404 as it didn't find any matching route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in order to achieve this you have two options: using inputs or creating a route compiler

### Using Inputs

You can make the url simply go to the `info` method with nothing special in the url:

```py
Get().route('/', 'PageController@info').name('info')
```

Then you can hit routes like `https://websiteopedia.com/?website=https://www.eventsnow.com/`

Then inside the `info` method, you would get the input as normal:

```py
def info(self, request: Request):
    request.input('website') #== 'https://www.eventsnow.com/'
```

### Route Compiler

A route compiler is simply a way to compile regex in the URL. You can make a new compiler in one of the boot methods in your service providers.

This new compiler would look like this:

```py
def boot(self, view: View):
    view.compile('url', r'([^\s]+)')
```

Then you can construct the route like this:

```py
Get().route('/@website:url', 'PageController@info').name('info')
```

This will now compile that into the regex you provided and you can now hit the routes like you were previously.